# Do mildly informative prior distributions tend to mitigate false positives (i.e. Type I error rates)?

Tags: regression, bayesian, references, prior, ridge-regression

I am curious if others have sources that speak to the matter that providing informative and/or mildly informative prior distributions on a parameter tend to mitigate false alarm rates? I know from the machine learning literature that the MAP estimates of Bayesian linear regression is equivalent to Ridge regression as the prior distribution functions as the ridge penalty here. I am wondering if there are resources you could point me to where I might find this answer as I am having trouble finding some.